# How to update form library by sending email?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I would like to update a particular column in a form library by sending an email. How can I achieve this? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Do the following to enable and configure the e-mail settings for a form library:-

1. **Open** the **library** for which you want to **enable** and configure e-mail settings.
2. On the **Settings** menu , click **Form Library Settings**.
3. Under **Communications**, click Incoming **e-mail** settings.

NOTE: The Incoming e-mail settings link is not available if incoming e-mail support is not enabled in Central Administration.

4. In the E-Mail section, click **Yes** to enable this library to receive e-mail.
5. In the **E-mail address** box, type a **unique name** to use as part of the e-mail address for this library.
6. In the **E-Mail Attachments** section, choose where to save and how to group e-mail attachments in this library, and then choose whether to overwrite files with the same name.
7. If you choose not to overwrite files with the same name and then later attempt to save a file with the same name as one that already exists in the library, four random digits are appended to the file name for the new attachment. If this action fails, a globally unique identifier (GUID) is appended to the file name. If neither of these actions can produce a unique file name, the attachment is discarded.
8. In the E-Mail Message section, choose whether to save the original e-mail message in this library.
9. If you choose **Yes**, the original message is saved as a separate item in the library.
10. In the E-Mail Meeting Invitations section, choose whether to **save attachments** to your meeting invitations in this library.
11. In the E-Mail Security section, choose whether to archive e-mail from only members of the site who can write to the library or to archive regardless of who sends the e-mail.

IMPORTANT: Archiving e-mail from all senders allows everyone (including unauthenticated users) to write to your library. Because of the potential security risk, you should give this option careful consideration.

1. Click **OK** to save your settings.

Hopefully, this will help you out.

Comment: If you need any further help in this topic, then do tell me.